# How to insert the values from 0 to 300 without duplicate insertion and 302 row value to be as 300+

Tags: sql-server-2008

i'm having a table called Time_check under which i have two columns

first column : TimeId which is auto increment

second column : time which is of int datatype

now i need to insert values into column Time from 0 to 300 and ma row after 300 will be 300+

as time column is int its not accepting varchar value 300+.

how will i do it ....??

output something like :

```
TimeId    Time

   1           0


   2          1

  .          .

  .          .

  301      300

 302      300+
```

Code which i tried was

```
set nocount on

Declare @row varchar(10);

set @row=0;

WHILE  not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Time_check)

BEGIN

  while(@row<=300)

begin

insert into [dbo].Time_check ([time]) valueS (@row)

set @row=@row+1;

end 

IF(@row=300)

declare @roww varchar(10)

set @roww='300+'

Insert into [dbo].Time_check([Time]) values (cast(@roww as int))

end
end
```

but i'm getting errors

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to change the datatype of your `time` column to varchar, since it is not possible to store the value '300+' in an int column.

Maybe you should shed a little more light on why you need to store this value in the `time` column of your table, instead of having your application's presentation layer handling this?